# Pass the values in Navigation React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have set up a function to navigate and pass data to another screen when the button is pressed. the problem is when i try to send a specific value(`serialNumber`) it shows as `undefined` in the console. But when I try some other values it passes correctly. following is **my code**

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.actionButton}
onPress={() => startTT(item.id , item.serialNumber, item.ttId, item.model)}>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**onPress function**

```
function startTT(serialNumber, ttID, id,) {
    console.log("startJob Serial", serialNumber)
    navigation.navigate('SerialNo', { PSerial: serialNumber , ttId: ttID, STId: id, dataOBJ: serviceTData })
}
```

**My Data Object**

```
Object {
  "actionTime": null,
  "arrivedAt": null,
  "callPerson": null,
  "category": null,
  "contactNo": "0",
  "createdAt": "2021-08-06 13:27:55",
  "custName1": null,
  "custName2": null,
  "geoLocation": null,
  "id": 1,
  "location": null,
  "remark": null,
  "repeat": null,
  "tasks": Array [
    Object {
      "completed": false,
      "createdAt": null,
      "model": "Lexmark:MS510DN",
      "product": "PRINTER",
      "remark": "paper jam",
      "serialNumber": "451444HH1N1GT",
      "status": null,
      "topic": "21080295T210",
      "ttId": 27226,
      "warrantyStatus": "MAINTENANCE_COMPREHENSIVE",
    },
  ],
  "topic": null,
  "visitingAdd1": "J/ HARTLEY COLLEGE,",
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is on `item.id`. For some reason is not equal to object you posted. Could you post some more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function startTT(serialNumber, ttID, id,) {
    console.log("startJob Serial", serialNumber)
    navigation.navigate('SerialNo', { PSerial: serialNumber , ttId: ttID, STId: id, dataOBJ: serviceTData })
}
//will pass PSerial, ttId, STId, and dataOBJ on the route parameter
```

in your other screen if you use functional component

```
const route = useRoute();
const {PSerial,ttId,STId,dataOBJ} = route.params;
```

if you use class components

```
const {PSerial,ttId,STId,dataOBJ} = this.props.route.params;
```

and then you can call the param on your stylesheet

```
<Text>{PSerial}</Text>
```

EDIT :
your function have 3 params and you add 4 params when you call it

this is the correct one

```
startTT(item.serialNumber, item.ttId, item.model)
```

Comment: when i try to `console` the value before sending it shows as `undefined` <== `console.log("startJob Serial", serialNumber)`

Comment: is it inside a flatlist with tasks as the data ?

Comment: maybe try to log the item first, perhaps your item is indeed undefined. onPress => console.log("MyItem",item)

Comment: because i see nothing wrong with your function

Comment: `MyItem Object {
  "completed": false,
  "createdAt": null,
  "model": "Lexmark:MS510DN",
  "product": "PRINTER",
  "remark": "paper jam",
  "serialNumber": "451444HH1N1GT",
  "status": null,
  "topic": "21080295T210",
  "ttId": 27226,
  "warrantyStatus": "MAINTENANCE_COMPREHENSIVE",
}` ==> `console.log` response. I think there is no issue in `item`

Comment: my bad dude, your function have 3 parameter

Comment: and your onPress call it 4 parameter

Answer (score 1):

```
function startTT(serialNumber, ttID, id,) {
console.log("startJob Serial", serialNumber)
navigation.navigate('SerialNo', { PSerial: serialNumber , ttId: ttID, STId: id, dataOBJ: serviceTData })
```

}

Try to console.log("startJob Serial", ttID) // you will get the serial number